# Getting formula from website calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

So this is an issue I come across frequently... there are many medical website calculators online that health systems would like to use, but the formulas, equations and statistical models aren't readily available. I was wondering if it would be possible to use Developer Tools on chrome or something similar to find these in the javascript? I can find pages of calculations when I mine into the data but nothing that makes sense to me. (EX: http://riskcalculator.facs.org/RiskCalculator/PatientInfo.jsp)

Comment: Assuming they implement their formulas in JavaScript then you could read the source code for the site. It might be minified which would make it more difficult. There's no technique or tool for doing this. You either need to figure out the formula yourself or scour through their code and hope you can recognize it when you see it.

Comment: I would guess they would want to obscure anything of real value. They could be using server-side scripts for things they don't want to share. Either way if you can't make sense of the javascript you need someone who can to even decide if the formulas are there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. If everything works on the client side you should be able to read the code if you really need it. There's an option to "prettify" the minified script in chrome dev tools (sources -> "{}" icon below the editor).

However, I'm not so sure if reusing it won't violate a law in some countries.

Also, I believe if this is some kind of expensive information, the website authors would rather send input to a server and send back a result. You could also do some reverse engineering by watching the I/O in numerous ways.

I'd suggest writing to them directly first and as if they are willing to share the algorithm with you.

Additionally just do a research on the topic you're interested in. Most of those calculators are using publicly accessible knowledge which is pretty easy to write as a script.